# Describe the Riemann Surface for $z^2 = w + \frac{1}{w}$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Describe the Riemann Surface for $z^2 = w + \frac{1}{w}$. Not sure if my process is correct. We can see $z = \frac{\sqrt{w^2+1}}{\sqrt{w}}$. So there are branch points at 0, i, -i. We have two layers, with two cuts. One from -i to i and one from 0 to infinity, where we glue the two surfaces together. Is this correct?

Comment: $(\sqrt w + 1/\sqrt w)^2 = w + 2 + 1/w$.

Comment: @Ennar i'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Ennar commented before your edit.

Comment: @MarkBennet my edit was just changing the branching points. His response didnt make sense before the edit either.

Comment: His comment did make sense, because your question contained the statement $z=\sqrt w+\frac 1{\sqrt w}$ at the time he commented. And he was simply pointing out that if you square the right-hand side of this equation you don't get $z^2=w+\frac 1w$, so it can't be right.

Comment: okay, so i did fix it. but how does this relate to the riemann surface?

Comment: A double cover of the Riemann sphere with four branch points is an elliptic curve (Riemann surface of genus $1$).